# Finding presence of chars or strings out of the allowed ones

Tags: php, preg-match, pcre, regex-negation

Well, I'm stuck, I cannot find the correct form for the RegEx to provide to the PHP preg_match.

I have two strings. Say `"mdo"` and `"o"`, but they could be really random.

I have a dictionary of allowed chars and strings.

For the example, allowed chars are `"a-gm0-9"`, and allowed strings are `"do"` and `"si"`.

**THE GOAL**

I'm trying to check that the input string **doesn't contain any char or string** but those in the dictionary, case-insensitive.

So the case of `"mdo"` wouldn't match because `m` is allowed just like the string `do`. Not the same for `o` instead, which has `o` that is not an allowed char and which doesn't contain the whole allowed string `do`.

**My struggling reason**

It's ok to negate `[^a-gm0-9]` and `(?!do|si)`, but what I cannot achieve is to place them inside a single regex in order to apply the following PHP code:

```
<?php
  $inputStr = 'mdo';
  $rex = '/?????/i';      // the question subject
  // if disallowed chars/strings are found...
  if( preg_match($regex, $inputStr) == 1 )
    return false;     // the $inputStr is not valid
  return true;
?>
```

Because two cascading preg_matches would break the logic and don't work.

How to mix chars check and groups check in "AND" in a single regex? Their positions don't matter.

Comment: It is more simple to check allowed characters and substrings and to negate the preg_match function itself in your if condition.

Comment: The main problem (I think) is that "do" and "si" both countain unallowed chars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
return (bool) preg_match('~^(?:do|si|[a-gm0-9])*+\C~i', $inputStr);
```

The idea is to match all allowed chars and substrings from the start in a repeated group with a [possessive quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) and to check if a single byte `\C` remains. Since the quantifier is greedy and possessive, the single byte after, if found, can't be allowed.

Note that most of the time, it is more simple to negate the `preg_match` function, example:

```
return (bool) !preg_match('~^(?:do|si|[a-gm0-9])*$~iD', $inputStr);
```

*(or with a `+` quantifier, if you don't want to allow empty strings)*

Comment: I have infinite regards for you guys who can handle regular expressions in this way...something like wizards or like that. It works great both versions. Thank you!